# Condition for list count and null

Tags: c#

I have following constructor as shown below:

```
public Delivery(DeliveryPeriodEnum deliveryPeriod, IEnumerable<DayOfWeek> days)
{
       _deliveryPeriod = deliveryPeriod;
       _days = days;

        if (_deliveryPeriod == DeliveryPeriodEnum.Nothing 
            && (_days != null || _days.Any())) 
            throw new GeneralException("There cannot be days for given period");

        if (_deliveryPeriod != DeliveryPeriodEnum.Nothing 
            && (_days == null || !_days.Any())) 
            throw new GeneralException("Period has to have at elast one item in list");
}
```

**There are two business conditions:**

```
//if DeliveryPeriodEnum.Nothing:
then days have to be either null or not null but with count = 0 otherwise show message

//if DeliveryPeriodEnum <> DeliveryPeriodEnum.Nothing:
then days cannot be null and have to have count > 0 otherwise show message
```

I have problems with it for instance in my first if statment if `DeliveryPeriodEnum  = DeliveryPeriodEnum .Nothing` `and days is null` it also evalueates to `_days.Any()` which certainly raise error of `instance not exist`.

**Keep in mind i would like to have both conditions in two lines if possible to avoid big if else statments etc..**

**EDIT:**

```
if (_deliveryPeriod == DeliveryPeriodEnum.Nothing 
    && _days != null && _days.Any()) 
    throw new GenericException("There cannot be days for given period");
if ((_deliveryPeriod != DeliveryPeriodEnum.Nothing && _days != null && !_days.Any())
    throw new GenericException("There cannot be days for given period");
```

Comment: What do you think happens when `_days == null` in `_days != null || _days.Any()`?

Comment: Also you should avoid any code that throws exceptions in constructors.

Comment: @Enigmativity it evaluates _days.Any() and trow exception, that's the point i would like to say at this point: "ok" list is null do not check count additionalyfor this case but i don't know how to handle also second case where list != null then also check count. Of course all in one line..

Comment: Check the property value exists or not. if(_deliveryPeriod.Any(x => x.property == value) {  // do something " else {  throw new GeneralException("There cannot be days for given period");}  . But in this case you could respond only one common exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check by `&&` not `||` as this condition can throw error `_days != null || _days.Any())`. Because `_days` can be `null`:

```
if (_deliveryPeriod == DeliveryPeriodEnum.Nothing 
    && (_days != null && _days.Any())) 
    throw new GeneralException("There cannot be days for given period");

if (_deliveryPeriod != DeliveryPeriodEnum.Nothing 
    && ((_days != null && !_days.Any()) || _days == null)) 
    throw new GeneralException("Period has to have at elast one item in list");
```

Comment: What happens with the code `_days == null 
    && !_days.Any()`?

Comment: @StepUp i think it's exactly what i've just wrote isn't it? :) Look at my EDIT section in my post. I think bracket in first condition is redundant

Comment: @Arie no, I've added extra squares and pay attention to your condition `(_days == null || !_days.Any()))`. As it can throw `NULL Reference Exception`. Because `!_days.Any()` can be NULL. However, you can rewrite your condition like this by adding `?` sign `!_days?.Any()`

Comment: ah you were right ! Finally i got first condition: if (_deliveryPeriod == DeliveryPeriodEnum.Nothing && _days != null && _days.Any())

Comment: second condition: if (_deliveryPeriod != DeliveryPeriodEnum.Nothing && _days != null && !_days.Any())

Comment: same as yours i;ve just remove redundant braces

Comment: hmm but hold on for second condition what if days is null will it throw also an exception, hmm

Comment: i thought so, because there could be (i mean shouldn't be - i;ve just don;t be live front end :) ) that _deliveryPeriod != DeliveryPeriodEnum.Nothing  and days =null

Comment: @Arie yeah, you can write like this. However, it will not work if `_days` is not null

Comment: in my view, yeah

Answer (score 1):

First condition:

> if DeliveryPeriodEnum.Nothing: then days have to be either null or not
>   null but with count = 0 otherwise show message

```
 if (!((_deliveryPeriod == DeliveryPeriodEnum.Nothing) && (_days == null || !_days.Any()))) 
     throw new GeneralException("There cannot be days for given period");
```

Second condition:

> if DeliveryPeriodEnum <> DeliveryPeriodEnum.Nothing: then days cannot
>   be null and have to have count > 0 otherwise show message

```
if (!((_deliveryPeriod != DeliveryPeriodEnum.Nothing) && (_days != null) && _days.Any())))
    throw new GeneralException("Period has to have at elast one item in list");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [null-conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) operator like below. When `_days` is null the comparison leads to `false` in the first comparison and `true` in the second one. When it's not null, it just evaluates the `.Any()` statement.

```
public Delivery(DeliveryPeriodEnum deliveryPeriod, IEnumerable<DayOfWeek> days)
{
       _deliveryPeriod = deliveryPeriod;
       _days = days;

        if (_deliveryPeriod == DeliveryPeriodEnum.Nothing && _days?.Any() == true)
            throw new GeneralException("There cannot be days for given period");

        if (_deliveryPeriod != DeliveryPeriodEnum.Nothing && (_days?.Any() ?? false) == false)
            throw new GeneralException("Period has to have at least one item in list");
}
```

Comment: wow, this looks line even shorter than other's/my asnwers. You sure no mistake there?

Comment: @Arie yeah, it should work as `?` will evaluate `_days?.` to `false` if `_days`  is `null`.

Comment: I think it lacks additional check in second statment when days are null because theoriticly it could be _deliveryPeriod != DeliveryPeriodEnum.Nothing and days = null - i mean such values could be passed in ctor argument

Comment: therefore not sure but second statment should be:    if (_deliveryPeriod != DeliveryPeriodEnum.Nothing && (_days?.Any() == false || _days == null)) what you think?

Comment: @Arie You are right. There should be another check in the second statement to make sure the evaluation to false works when _days is null. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Is your updated ststment same as: _days?.Any() == false || _days == null ?